Incomprehensible Phase portrait method for $x''+x-x^3=0$

Given the differential equation $x''+x-x^3=0$ where $x(0)=0$, $x'(0)=x_0$. Using the Phase portrait method, determine when the solution to a differential equation is periodic

Let's introduce a new variable $ v = x' $. Then the equation will be rewritten as the system
$$
\begin{cases}
x' = v, \\
v' = -x + x^3.
\end{cases}
$$
The energy approach involves introducing the Hamilton function, which will be an invariant of motion. To do this, we find the energy function $E$, which is conserved for a given system. Let us introduce the Lyapunov function
$$
E(x, v) = \frac{v^2}{2} + \int_0^x (s - s^3) \, ds.
$$
Let's calculate the integral
$$
\int_0^x (s - s^3) \, ds = \left[ \frac{s^2}{2} - \frac{s^4}{4} \right]_0^x = \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{4}.
$$
This function must be constant on the trajectories of the phase plane. That is, $E(x, v) = \text{const}$. Let us consider when the trajectories of the phase plane are closed, which corresponds to periodic solutions. Closed trajectories correspond to energy levels for which the function $ E(x, v)$ is bounded.
$$
E(x, v) = \frac{v^2}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{4}.
$$
Note that the function $ E $ will be bounded if $ \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{4} $ remains non-negative. For this purpose $ \frac{x^4}{4} \leq \frac{x^2}{2} $. Multiplying both sides by 4, we get
$$
x^4 \leq 2x^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x^2(x^2 - 2) \leq 0\Leftrightarrow x^2-2\leq 0\Rightarrow x \in [-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]
$$
The phase portrait will contain closed trajectories (and therefore the solution will be periodic) if the initial value $ x $ lies in the interval $ [-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}] $. Since the initial condition $ x(0) = 0$ always satisfies this condition, it remains to analyze the initial value of the speed $ x'(0) = x_0$. In order for the solution $ x(t) $ to remain limited and the trajectories to be closed, the value of the initial velocity $ x_0 $ must be such that it does not exceed the energy corresponding to the critical points $ x = \pm\sqrt{2} $. This condition will be satisfied if the energy of the initial state $ \frac{x_0^2}{2} $ is less than the maximum energy of the system $ E(\sqrt{2}, 0) $
$$
E(\sqrt{2}, 0) = \frac{(\sqrt{2})^2}{2} - \frac{(\sqrt{2})^4}{4} = 1 - 1 = 0
$$
The solution to the differential equation will be periodic provided that the initial energy does not exceed zero (the maximum permissible for closed trajectories)
This is my first time encountering such a task and I would like to understand whether I approached it and solved it correctly?

You have identified the zeroes of the potential energy function as $\pm\sqrt2,$ but that should not be compared with the initial position, which is given as $0$ anyway. Bounded periodic solutions depend on the initial velocity compared to the maximum of the potential energy. So you need to identify the boundaries of the "energy well", which is the same as the places where the potential energy reaches a maximum, which is at two of the three zeroes of the force field $x-x^3,$ namely $-1$ and $1.$ In both cases the potential energy is $\frac12-\frac14=\frac14$ (where we have stuck to the convention that the potential energy is $0$ at $x=0$). The system is bounded periodic if and only if the initial kinetic energy is less than or equal to $1/4,$ i.e., the absolute value of the initial velocity is less than or equal to $\sqrt2/2.$

Thanks for helping me figure it out!

I took a look but it's out of my comfort zone.
